# How should I center this logo on a T-shirt?

Tags: logo

[image: logo]I'm not a designer, but I can't afford one right now. So I made this logo for my podcast on Canva. I like the idea of making it a clean, simple logo like the Nike logo. I used a spark graphic from Canva, which also looks like the S in the word spark. I'm trying to combine the spark with the words Spark The Genius like the Nike swoosh goes with the word Nike. But this spark is vertical, while the swoosh in horizontal, so it makes things different. Maybe I should rotate the spark to be horizontal. But that will be another question. For this question... I've posted the logo on T-shirts in an online store. But now I'm realizing I centered it based on the entire logo and that maybe I should be centering it based on just the letters? Or maybe I should split the difference?

Comment: That lightning bolt is just too large compared to the text. No amount of centering will fix it.

Comment: Centering is boring... small, upper, right breast is more elegant.

Comment: You could simply adjust it's position by eye. Move it until it looks well balanced and centred. Don't make it geometrically centred based on measurements, or it will look off.

Comment: Cool logo for a non-designer.

Comment: To better appreciate the proportions, also rotate your t-shirt with logo, and also make it blurry or squint your eyes. That way your brain will not process in a normal way but might look a shapes and spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Centering by the whole image is no problem,as you see:

[image]

[image]

The placement is the same in both versions, there's only done a partial color inversion to get the dark shirt. As a print it's, of course much trickier to be made.